# Service constructor parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constructor, angular-services

If I'm not wrong, in angular a service defines a function that will be the constructor of the service object

```
angular.module('HelloModule', []).service('MyService', function(myParam){
    this.myThing = myParam; 
    this.getThing = function () { return this.myThing; };
});
```

Now, since it is supposed to be a singleton I tough that the constructor would be called only the first time the service is instantiated, so the `this.myThing = myParam;` would be called only at creation time.

When the service already exists in the application because somewhere was already required/injected the constructor is it still invoked or not?

I know that when the instance already exists angular will return the instance itself but what about the statement `this.myThing = myParam;` will be skipped or not?

**EDIT**
being more specific, I'm using *angular ui Router* and in my constructor I have

```
angular.module('HelloModule', []).service('MyService', function($state){
    this.state = $state;
});
```

each time I use the service from different controllers the `this.state` is set to the correct value. 
This is exactly what I don't understand. Shouldn't `this.state` be set to the first value of `$state` at instantiation time and never change?

Comment: Why do you need set this.state = $state? I don't understand. If you try to acces $state via html markup just use $rootScope.state = $state it top level controller.

Comment: i have edited for you. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Actualy, I believe that there is no need to inject $state into another service and bound it to another property if you don't want to change or extend its properties. Just inject it anywhere you need it.

Because $satate is a provider and it will always bounded until it is not cloned. If you use this.state = angular.extend({}, $state) it would be not bounded. You would get different state provider for each service definition ant it may couse recursive problems.

**Old**

you can not pass **myParam** like that, Use like below

```
  angular.module('HelloModule', []).service('MyService', [function(){
         var myThing; 
         this.init = function(myParam){
              myThing = myParam;
         }
         this.getThing = function () { return this.myThing; };
  }]);

 //in any other services, directives controllers etc call servce
 var params = {}
 var servise = new MyService.init(params)
```

In your code, angular understand that you would try to dependency injection **myParams**

Like below

```
  angular.module('HelloModule', []).service('MyService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http){
         var myThing; 
         this.init = function(myParam){
              myThing = myParam;
         }
         this.getThing = function () { return this.myThing; };
  }]);
```

Namely you have tried to inject myParams, like  $rootScope, $http etc.

As I understand you would try to do this.

```
angular.module('HelloModule', ['ui.router']).service('MyService', ['$state', function($state){
     this.state = $state; 
     this.getThing = function () { return this.myThing; };
 }]);


//in your app
angular.module('app',['HelloModule'])
```

Comment: I've made an edit to be more specific but I guess my problem is related dependency injection as you mentioned

Comment: Did you inject HelloModule to your app? Also if you HelloModule as seperate module, you must inject uiRouter to angular.module('HelloModule', ['uiRouter']) like this.

Comment: yes, my problem is not why things don't work it is more 'why things work anyway?'. So as I see it now, things work because I inject the $state service in the `MyService`? This is sufficient to justify the fact that `this.state` is always the correct `$state` value in different controllers (way later after the first instantiation)? Meaning that `this.state` is variable and it is  always bound to `$state`, this was the dark part I could not get

Comment: Sorry! I don't understand what you try to do :( Did you try exted $state service or any part of its? You should make clear about your expectation.

Comment: no, what I do is what you describe on you last code block and it works! What I don't understand is why `this.state` is always bound to `$state` (always the correct $state for different controllers). Shouldn't `this.state = $state` be evaluated only at instantiation time?

Comment: Because $satate is a provider and it will always bounded until it is not cloned. If you use this.state = angular.extend({}, $state) it would be not bounded. You would get different state provider for each service definition ant it may couse recursive problems.

Comment: Actualy, I believe that there is no need to inject $state into another service and bound it to another property if you don't want to change or extend its properties. Just inject it anywhere you need it.

Comment: Could you please include your comment "Because $satate is a.." in the answer so that I can accept it? This was in fact the answer to my doubts

Answer (score 0):

A service is not 'supposed to be a singleton', a factory is a singleton and a service is an instance. They both work in the same way the only difference is:

```
var service = (function(){
    var serviceConstructor = function(){}; //the constructor in your question
    return new service;
}();
```

and

```
var factory = (function(){
    return { foo: 'bar'};
}();
```

This is why you can use `this` inside your constructor.

A service will be instantiated only once, this same instance is then used globally....

In your example there is a typo you are returning `this.myThing` but scoping `var myThing` and so its not returning anything.

To answer your question `myThing` will not be skipped, it will be set to your depedency `myParam` when it is instantiated.

Comment: So only the first time it is instantiated then. Not all the times that is injected?

Comment: Correct, the same instance is then injected

Comment: Services and factories are both singletons but a service is instantiated with the new keyword.